# return original input class when deleting content

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, input

i made a input where the user enters the email address.

```
input(
    :class="hasError? 'border-red-600': 'border-green-700'"
    id="email"
    v-model="email"
    type="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="type your email"
    required
    )
```

on error, hasError is set to true

How can I build v-bind or method to return the original class 'border-green-700' when the user starts deleting the email that returned error? what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used keypress with a method to set hasError false

```
input(
    @keypress="checkInput"
    :class="hasError? 'border-red-600': 'border-green-700'"
    id="email"
    v-model="email"
    type="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="type your email"
    required
    )
```

and method

```
methods: {
  checkInput: function() {
    this.hasError = false
  }
}
```